# Firestore - Write document with same id more than once per second

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Updating the same document in Firestore can lead to contention and so it is recommended to only update a document once per second.

What about creating a new document with the same ID and fields? Would it lead to contention if you overwrite the existing document? For example, if you ran this more than once per second (using the same document id):

```
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("cities").document("new-city-id").setData(data: [
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "country": "Japan"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's effectively the same thing as updating a document (with the addition that existing fields are also deleted).  It falls under the same document write limits.  The type of write operation doesn't matter, it's the path of the document that's being written that matters.

This is something that you should be able to test for yourself by writing a loop.  Eventually, under sustained load, one of the write operations will fail.